# Управление стрелками по grid сетке JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Скачал расширение для Chrome с гитхаба которое горячими клавишами открывает окно вкладок, для удобного перемещения. Там есть пользовательский CSS, сделал отображение вкладок в виде грид сетки, только перемещение по ним по умолчанию кнопками вверх и вниз, помогите сделать перемещение стрелками право/лево/вверх/вниз.!

```js
function focusPrev(skip) {
  skip = skip || 1;
  entryWithFocus().removeClass('withfocus').prevAll(".item").eq(skip - 1).addClass('withfocus');
  if (!isFocusSet()) {
    (skip === 1 ? focusLast : focusFirst)();
  }

  scrollToFocus();
}

function focusNext(skip) {
  skip = skip || 1;
  entryWithFocus().removeClass('withfocus').nextAll(".item").eq(skip - 1).addClass('withfocus');
  if (!isFocusSet()) {
    (skip === 1 ? focusFirst : focusLast)();
  }

  scrollToFocus();
}


 $(document).on('keydown.down', function() {
    focusNext();
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on('keydown.up', function() {
    focusPrev();
    return false;
  });
```

[Файл popup в котором хранятся записи хот кеев](https://my-files.ru/Save/crbj4b/popup.js)

[image: display grid for tabs popup]

Answer (score 1):

```
skip = skip || 3;
```

вместо

```
skip = skip || 1;
```

для трех колонок соответственно.